# Cardinality of ultraproducts

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, filters

This might be a trivial question, but I couldn't see how to do this now. 
Given an infinite model $M$ and infinite cardinal $\kappa > |M|$ and a non-principal ultrafilter $F$ over $\kappa$, is it always true that $N = M^\kappa/F$ has cardinality $\geq \kappa$? If not, is it sometimes true?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: If $|M|=1$, then $|N|=1$.

Comment: @markvs And if $|M|$ is finite, then $|N| = |M|$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: That is also correct. For infinite $M$ the statement may be true.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have edited my question so that $M$ is assumed to be infinite. If the statement always true? Are there examples where this is true and examples where this is false?

Comment: It is always true iff it is true for the set $M=\omega$.

Comment: If $κ$ is measurable cardinal, and $F$ is $κ$-complete, $|N|$ cannot be greater than $|M|$

Comment: You may want some extra assumption on $F$ such as uniformity. If $F$ is concentrated on a very small set then the ultrapower would not be very large.

Comment: If $\kappa$ is countable, then $|N|\ge 2^\kappa$ provided $M$ is infinite.

Comment: @ℋolo: I thought that the existence of measurable cardinals is unprovable. Isn't it?

Comment: @markvs it is unprovable, but it tells us at least that ZFC cannot prove (assuming measurables are consistent) what OP is asking

Comment: @ℋolo: OK ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think $|N|$ could be smaller than $\kappa$ for some trivial reason: if $F$ contains a set $X$ of size $\lambda$ such that $|M|^\lambda<\kappa$, then $N=M^\kappa/F$ is the same as $M^\lambda/F'$ where $F'$ is the restriction of $F$ on $X$, so has size at most $|M|^\lambda<\kappa$.

If $F$ is uniform then the question becomes more interesting (probably more difficult too). If $|M|$ is countable and $F$ is countably *in*complete, then $|N|$ is at least continuum, see section 5 of [this survey](https://people.math.wisc.edu/%7Ekeisler/ultraproducts-web-final.pdf).

[Here](https://spot.colorado.edu/%7Ekearnes/S16/ultrafilters.pdf) is another short note which I vaguely remember but it took some time to find it again...If $F$ is regular then $N$ has the largest size possible, namely $|M|^\kappa$. Also from [here](https://books.google.nl/books?id=pLxq0myANiEC&pg=PA483&lpg=PA483&dq=cardinality%20of%20an%20ultrapower&source=bl&ots=0ChcEFwU3B&sig=Jb6KJS6ga4VexT-XbMg0dKTu7IM&hl=nl&ei=oGjzS-aHDtKEsAbFt5DqCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CBsQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=cardinality%20of%20an%20ultrapower&f=false) it seems the general question is indeed quite difficult.

Comment: "some trivial reason", if $cof(|M|)=\omega$ and $\kappa$ small enough, this argument falls as it is now. I think that there may be cases of uncountable $M$ that are also interesting to look at

Answer (score 5):

This is only a partial answer.

If $κ>|M|^+$ and $F$ is $|M|^{++}$-complete then $|M|=|N|$, if not, let $(f_i\mid i\in|M|^+)$ be a (possibly partial) listing of representatives of elements of $N$

Let $D_{i,j}$ be the set of indices where $f_i$ and $f_j$ disagree, this is a $F$-big set, in particular $\bigcap_{i<j\in|M|^+}D_{i,j}$ is not empty, if $m\in \bigcap_{i<j\in\lambda}D_{i,j}$ we have
$f_i(m)≠f_j(m)$ for all $i,j∈λ$ so $|\{f_i(m)\mid i\in |M|^+\}|=|M|^+>|M|$, contradiction.

Comment: Which part of it is independent of ZFC?

Comment: @markvs the existence of cardinal $\kappa$ such that there exists $\kappa$ complete ultrafilter on $\kappa$ is independent (it is equivalent to "$\kappa$ is measurable"), I'm not sure if about what ZFC can prove about cardinals $\kappa$ that are $\lambda^{++}$-complete for some $\lambda<\kappa$ (which is all I used)

Comment: If there exists a countably complete ultrafilter then there is a measurable cardinal.

Comment: @Lxm so my answer depends on measurables even as is, Thanks!