# Existence of ultrapower of arbitrary cardinality

Tags: model-theory, filters

Given an infinite structure $\mathcal M$ and a cardinal $\kappa$, prove there exists an ultrapower $\mathcal M^I/U$ that has cardinality $\kappa$.

The motivation is to use ultrapower to prove upwards Lowenheim Skolem ( exercise 4.24 of this [note](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/atserunyan/Courses/2016F.Math571.MT/Henson--van%20den%20Dries.pdf)). From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4336262/1008277) it seems a regular ultrafilter suffices, but I would imagine the solution to be more elementary than that. Any hint?

Comment: Do you want cardinality exactly $\kappa$ or at least $\kappa$? (The former is impossible in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ alone: if $\mathsf{CH}$ fails, then no countably infinite structure has an ultrapower of size $\aleph_1$.)

Comment: I think at least $\kappa$ is fine.